# Is it possible to use the DeclareFontShape command with kpfonts?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, size, kpfonts

In my work, I've been using the fourier package to get a nice typography and I've been capable of add a lot of different types of math text styles

[image]

and with a proper size thanks to the `\DeclareFontShape` command **except** with the kpfonts' fraktur style. The way that I get this style is with

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{U}{jkpmia}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{bold}{U}{jkpmia}{bx}{it}
```

in the preamble but I don't know how to use `\DeclareFontShape` here because there's not a `\DeclareFontFamily` command. So...

Is there a way to modify the size of the fraktur style with the code that I provide or is there another way to get this style that allows to use a `\DeclareFontShape` command or is impossible?

Comment: D.R. Rivera , I understand 'U" stands for unknown font encoding ; but what does 'jkpmia' stand for? I have looked at the web but was not able to get an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just scale the Fraktur font by adding `s*[0.9]` to the `\DeclareFontShape` where `0.9` is the scaling factor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{jkpmia}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{jkpmia}{m}{it}{<->s*[0.9]jkpmia}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{jkpmia}{bx}{it}{<->s*[0.9]jkpbmia}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{U}{jkpmia}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{bold}{U}{jkpmia}{bx}{it}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{ABCD} \mathfrak{ABCD}$
\boldmath
$\mathcal{ABCD} \mathfrak{ABCD}$
\end{document}
```

[image]