# Alternative separate font to mathfrak for small letters

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I am looking for a second set of alphabets for my article.

I have seen this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/358318/exist-a-calligraphic-fonts-free-similar-at-mathtime-pro-2-curly-script)  which looks great but it does not cover small letters (only capitals).

`\mathfrak` is a good option too, except for a very ugly and ambiguous `x` letter:

[image: mathfrak]

I am wondering if there is another alternative which covers small letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\mathfrak{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \\
&\mathfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The font should be different enough to be distinguished from normal default font but readable enough so no ambiguity happens.

Comment: The ol' `\mathfrak x`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320403/how-to-typeset-a-gothic-r-symbol-with-a-curl.  That answer has thirty-leven fonts you don't want.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, all look the same. Cannot use them for an academic paper.

Comment: Looking through my font library for more conventional "x"es: FRAKTUR: wieynkfraktur, schmalfettefraktur, Luftwaffe, Frankenstein, Fraktur, kabinettfraktur.  BASTARDA: kanzlei, worn manuscript, yonkers, belwe gotisch, cimbrian, lucida black, washington text.  ROTUNDA: Boer Tudor, Goudy Medieval, Augusta, typographer rotunda, Goudy Thirty, Weiss Rundgotisch, Alpine. TEXTURA: Werbedeutsch heavy, Frederick text, blackwood castle, Harrowgate, Lohengrin, Progressive Text, Old English Five, Canterbury, Old English, Iglesia, Diploma, Cloister Black, Old London, headline text, English towne, ...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, Many thanks but I dont know how to use for example wieynkfraktur. I use `\wieynkfraktur` but it is not a recognized command.

Comment: These are not packages I mentioned, but fonts.  If you find and download the font from the internet, and use xelatex or lualatex, you can access the glyphs.  Then, additional configuration will be required to use it in math mode.  For example, http://www.1001fonts.com/wieynk-fraktur-font.html

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, My problem is that I do not see any MWE code using them.

Comment: I am no expert, but it would involve the `mathspec` package, with the `\setmathfont` macro.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, does `\setmathfont` influence all fonts? I need to change a small region my article only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is compiled in LuaLaTeX.  I can use `\setmathfont` with the `range` specifier to limit the extent of the font substitution.  Here, I set the math font to `Old English Text MT` found by default on Windows systems, but limit it to the range of `\mathfrak`.  In essence, it substitutes only for `\mathfrak`, until the `\setmathfont` is used to later reset the feature to the `Latin Modern Math` defaults.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
\setmathfont[range=\mathfrak]{Old English Text MT}
Here we have $\mathfrak{x}^{55}+1 \ne(x^5)^{11}+1$

$\mathfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

$\mathfrak{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

\hrulefill

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
Here we have $\mathfrak{x}^{55}+1 \ne(x^5)^{11}+1$

$\mathfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

$\mathfrak{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternately, if the new fraktur font replacement is already available for pdflatex, then an approach like this can be used (based on the answer at [Is it possible to use the DeclareFontShape command with kpfonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331689/is-it-possible-to-use-the-declarefontshape-command-with-kpfonts)):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fourier}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{jkpmia}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{jkpmia}{m}{it}{<->s*jkpmia}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{jkpmia}{bx}{it}{<->s*jkpbmia}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{U}{jkpmia}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{bold}{U}{jkpmia}{bx}{it}
\begin{document}
Here we have $\mathfrak{x}^{55}+1 \ne(x^5)^{11}+1$

$\mathfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$

$\mathfrak{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here are some freely available fonts included in TeX Live. But Fraktur is inherently ambiguous, see C, E and G, for instance or A and U.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\alphabet}{abcdefghijklmnopqrs\/tuvwxyz}
\newcommand{\Alphabet}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpgoth}{OT1}{pgoth}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathesstixfrak}{U}{esstixfrak}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathboondoxfrak}{U}{BOONDOX-frak}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{amsfonts}
$\mathfrak{\alphabet}$\\
$\mathfrak{\Alphabet}$

\subsubsection*{pgoth}
$\mathpgoth{\alphabet}$\\
$\mathpgoth{\Alphabet}$

\subsubsection*{esstixfrak}
$\mathesstixfrak{\alphabet}$\\
$\mathesstixfrak{\Alphabet}$

\subsubsection*{boondox-frak}
$\mathboondoxfrak{\alphabet}$\\
$\mathboondoxfrak{\Alphabet}$

\end{document}
```

The `\/` is in order to avoid ligatures.

[image]

Comment: where can I find a list of such fonts? I'm trying to use `lucida` or `mma` frak (it appears alongside `esstixfrak` and `BOONDOX-frak` in this list https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode) but when I use your `\DeclareMathAlphabet` command for `{lucida}` instead for example it doesn't work.